# RavenDb Data Subscriptions PropertyMatch with Or condition

Tags: ravendb

Im new to RavenDb.Im working on RavenDb's data subscriptions. I have a scenario where I want subcription to trigger when a property has a value from a list of values. If that property has any value from a list of permitted values RavenDb should notify my event handler.

> For example I have a property named Event and if it has any value from [1,2,3,4,5], I want subscription to trigger.

In SubscriptionCriteria you can specify PropertiesToMatch which is a Dictionary, but it is like AND condition. It requires that document must have all these values.Is there a way to have an OR condition with RavenDb data subscriptions.
Using PropertieNotMatch and excluding all values other than the desired ones is also not feasible for me because values are not coming from a static list.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With RavenDB 4.0 you can create a subscription using **JavaScript filtering**.

See example and read about **Subscriptions Complex Conditional** in:

https://github.com/ravendb/book/blob/v4.0/Ch05/Ch05.md#complex-conditionals